# How do i replace the battery in this smoke detector? It wont stop beeping

Tags: smoke-detectors, alarm, fire

[image]

Its been beeping for ages and im sick of it, ive tried sliding as it says to but ive had no luck...

Comment: That slide to remove is probably for the entire unit, not just a cover.  Are you sliding the whole thing?

Comment: It feels like if i try to slide it any harder itll break off. Ive tried sliding just the bit that looks like a cover as well as the whole thing

Comment: That entire plastic shell - everything visible - is what comes off. There are no seams.I suspect the resistance you're feeling is actually the latch.  If it's not, and *merely removing the cover breaks it*, then it's a defective unit.  "old plastic rot" is not a problem for smoke detectors, since smoke detectors have a service life (owing to the internal radiation source which decays to uselessness; don't worry it can't harm you).

Comment: “Slide” is probably a misnomer. It should read “pull”.

Comment: Oh ok well there is actually a gap between the ceiling and that shell and its a bit like an upside down mushroom but ill try getting the whole thing off in a minute! I couldnt see any latch or anything like that though

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing and noticed there is a little latch under the text "slide to remove" which had to be lifted (with a screwdriver) to get the unit out from the ceiling. At least in Finnish version there was a text "lift the latch to slide unit off" which I noticed when I took a picture below the lid.

I know it's an ancient post but I thought this might help someone! :)